# Evitar que dos botones sean cliqueados al mismo tiempo (HTML, JS, VUE.js)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Tengo una card cuyo btn para poder ser expandida es el siguiente (code HTML generado):

```
<button data-v-5d473948="" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#module-collapse-" aria-controls="module-collapse-" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-toggle-collapse collapsed"><i data-v-5d473948="" class="icon ion-chevron-up"></i> <i data-v-5d473948="" class="icon ion-chevron-down"></i></button>
```

Code en mi componente de VUE.js:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-toggle-collapse"
  type="button"
  data-toggle="collapse"
  aria-expanded="false"
  data-target="#module-collapse-"
  aria-controls="module-collapse-"
  >
    <i class="icon ion-chevron-up"></i>
    <i class="icon ion-chevron-down"></i>
</button>
```

El problema que tengo es que a veces hay muchas cards, y cada card tiene un btn de esos, cuando intento expandir la segunda o tercera card, se expanden todas.

Answer (score 2):

Con la información suministrada y asumiendo que estás utilizando Bootstrap 4.6.

Esto lo más seguro se deba a que no has modificado los atributos data-target de tus botones o los identificadores de las cards.

Podrás encontrar un poco más de documentación en la página web de bootstrap en su versión 4.6 correspondiente al tema del uso de 'collapse'. [Enlace aquí.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/collapse/)